# To give dynamic alias name to my query in pl/sql

Tags: oracle, dynamic, plsql, alias, plsqldeveloper

I want to convert this code :

```
SELECT column_name as hard_code_value
  from table_name
 WHERE some_column = &parameter;
```

to somewhat like this

```
SELECT column_name as (select some_value from some_other_table_name)
  from table_name
 WHERE some_column = &parameter;
```

I have tried using pivot too but there too couldn't use dynamic values in 'IN' condition: 
I want to add a table value as an alias name. Is it possible?

Comment: You cannot dynamically define the name of a column or table with static SQL like that.  You can however use dynamic SQL to achieve what you want, but depending on your use case that might not work for you.  Can you clarify how this SQL is going to be run (from a program, by a user with a SQL client, etc)?

Comment: I want to run the query on plsql developer to check if my ticket is approved or not, and the alias name would be different approver. I want to set the alias name as an approver from a table. And can you show me how can I use dynamic sql to achieve what I want?

Comment: Then dynamic SQL will not work.  You cannot build and execute dynamic SQL in any client tool, like SQL Developer, that I am aware of.  To do it you would need write and program of some kind.  The closest I think you could get would be to write a PL/SQL package that returns a cursor which you would execute and then review the results of, but I"m not sure that is what you want.